# Retrieving GPS coordinates using Android: which version to use?

Tags: android, gps

I've found a lot of tutorials for retrieving GPS coordinates, but version compatibilities are unclear to me. I'm working on a group project and we have made some progress using Android 2.1. Now we're looking for a good GPS example and they all use different versions than what we use. Is there any Android GPS coordinate retriever code that is compatible with version 2.1, or would it be best to do the project using a newer version, like in this tutorial: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html#locationapi

Answer (score 5):

According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) the location API is there since the very first Android version. You can use it on *any* Android device irrespective of OS version.

Answer (score 2):

Like Hanno said right from the first version of Android, the software has supported GPS, if you want to check for *hardware* support use this :

```
public boolean isGpsAvailable() {
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
    return pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_LOCATION_GPS);
}
```